# Is it a bad practice to put Insert/Update/Delete/Select into a single stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

So we're told that Stored Procs are optimized and we should NEVER be putting sql statements into code.

But I don't want to make 10,000 stored procedure for every single type of query or db manipulation that I need.

So I've started doing something like this (putting all functions into a single sproc):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTABLENAME]
@Function nvarchar = null,
@ID int = null,
@MoreVariables int = null

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @Function = 'UPDATE'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE UPDATESTUFF WHERE ID = @ID;
    END
ELSE IF @Function = 'INSERT'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TABLENAME (STUFF)
    END
ELSE IF @Function = 'SELECT'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM TABLENAME  WHERE ID= @ID
    END
ELSE IF @Function = 'DELETE'
    BEGIN
        DELETE * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID = @ID  
    END
```

END

Can someone tell me if there is anything WRONG with doing things this way?

Comment: The value of stored procedures is in providing a contract between the database and an application.  If you write "can do everything" stored procedures, your contract doesn't provide any limitations.  That defeats the whole point.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to start with 1 simple question. Why?

Comment: You will need to pass unnecessary parameters to this procedure for most calls. For example, you will need to pass all columns required for an insert even when deleting requires just the ID.

Comment: @ron - thats not true... the parameters are null and not required.  If you want to delete you send in Function = "DELETE" and ID ... If you want to select ALL from the table, you simply send in Function = 'SELECT'

Comment: If this is a good approach for you why write stored procedure at all? Just open up the database for your ORM of choice.

Comment: @Jodrell - well I still suspect that using optimized (Cached) stored procs is better than having SQL statements in your code, that would be the why.

Comment: How well do you think this Stored Procedure would be optimized? Its called the first time, it returns some data. The second it deletes a row ...

Comment: When Entity Framework is used with MSSQL it sends all statements to the database via the `sp_ExecuteSql` system SP so when a statement is repeated optimization is achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly common to use a single "UPSERT" procedure, but one that also can potentially return data doesn't feel right to me...

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you use individual stored procs, you can get some extra benefit from cache plans and stuff that you might not benefit from with an all-in-one routine.

Comment: could you expand on 'cache plans'?

Comment: toddv, check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx   Essentially, though, the SQL engine will try to run a stored procedure in a way that it thinks is best, based on how it's been called in the past.  For very simple commands, it might not matter much, but if you had a complex query for the SELECT and the all-in-one routine was optimized for, say, DELETING, the SELECT query might not perform as well as if it had been in its own stored procedure.

Comment: @toddv The primary benefit (security aside) of Sotred Procedures is the performance improvement they yield. You encapsulate some set based operation into a fixed statement. The Database Engine then calculates the "best way" to perform that operation. For a Stored Procedure the "best way" is cached so it does not need to be recalculated for each run and can be reused. If a Stored Procedure, like yours, has procedural logic in it, that caching is either impared or it can prove detremential to performance.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of defeats the point and purpose of using Stored Procedures.

There's nothing wrong with having a single stored proc which can determine whether to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a user, say, depending on whether they alredy exist. But having a 'generic' stored proc to do everything is not very helpful.

If I was a developer coming to work on your project and I wanted to write a data access class to manipulate your users, I'd rather come across these
`sp_AddUser`, `sp_DeleteUser`, `sp_UpdateUserAddress` etc. than just:

`sp_doStuffToUsers`

That's a good enough reason in itself to my mind!

Comment: I see your point and it's valid.  But we have A LOT of tables... why make three SP's for each table when you could make one that takes a FUNCTION parameter that will do the same thing?

Comment: For the same reason you have lots of tables and not one massive one! A better reason is that your different 'functions' may take variable numbers of parameters. So INSERT may take 10, while UPDATE only needs 6. Now imagine in a year's time you have an extra field to add when INSERTING but not UPDATING - it all gets a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

You should only combine multiple crud statements into a single stored procedure when they are related.

SQL suffers from procedural language complexity. making them too big will eventually become a problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is correct that not to write SQLs at all. We could have SQLs in the code as long as the SQL is small. For complex joins, we could create views and then use them in the code.
If the query is very large or you are trying to get or build some data by making multiple queries, then Stored procedure is an option.
That said, you don't need to bundle SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT into a stored procedure as it impacts the readability and increases the complexity of the stored procedure causing maintenance problems.

Comment: Could someone please comment on the downvote ? Can't understand how SQLs in code is a complete ban as per OP.